# Trying to make the accordion collapsible open slower

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the accordion collapsible dropdown open a little slower, right now it opens instantly. Been trying to find online material on how to accomplish this with the code I already have. Can't seem to find anything online.

Any dropdown slowness, just trying to learn how to implement the code.

```css
.so-accordion-wrapper {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 820px;
}

.so-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.so-tab label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.so-tab input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.so-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .35s;
}

/* :checked */
.so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
    max-height: none;
}

/* Icon */
.so-tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #959595;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {

  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">INGREDIENTS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Yes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-2">PRECAUTION</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>No</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are tone of examples online for CSS slide down and up, and JS slide effects... The fact that you didn't find any its impossible.

Comment: @ikiK, Does it need to be done by JS? I was trying to keep it within css

Comment: @ikiK Pure CSS is almost always preferable over JS for something like this unless CSS just can't do it - the more client-side processing you add to your site, the slower it loads which is bad for user s *and* Google. As for other answers - I would agree with this normally, but the code appears to have some strange behaviour... even when you make the one change needed, the slide up and slide down work at different speeds.... very odd!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you asked in a comment, here is what I mean:

**Firstly, the only change you need is for to give `max-height` a value - "none" doesn't work.**

You have already addressed the usual problem when doing a slide up/down in CSS - you cannot transition `height` - by using `max-height` which can be used for transitions. However it needs a value for the transition to work, unfortunately `none` won't work because the browser cannot calculate the values needed for the transition with no value.

FYI there is also no need to change the `transition-timing-function` (e.g. `ease`, `ease-in-out`, `cubic-bezier`) or add a transition to the open div (that doesn't actually do anything in your code).

**The issue I mentioned** is that the slide down action is happening much more quickly than the time you have specified, i.e. `0.35s` - you can see it more clearly if you set it to e.g. `1s`. The slide-up action takes longer as if it is taking the correct amount of time. See example:

```css
.so-accordion-wrapper {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 820px;
}

.so-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.so-tab label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.so-tab input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.so-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

/* :checked */
.so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
    max-height: 1000px;
}

/* Icon */
.so-tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #959595;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {

  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">INGREDIENTS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Yes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-2">PRECAUTION</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>No</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The reason for this is that the time to slide down is being calculated on the `max-height`** you have set - e.g. `1000px` in the example above. So it is taking the full 1-second to slide down 1000px, but your actual div isn't that big so it appears much more quickly.

FYI the same is happening on the slide-up, but it looks slower because it takes almost the full second to reach the "top" of the 1000px that is being shown.

**The ways around this are:**

- use a more appropriate `max-height`, e.g. if you know your div is never going to be
  bigger than 100px;, then set that to your max height - see the example below.
- javascript (which should be avoided unless necessary and the above option is unacceptable to you - the more more processing you add to the client-side the slower the page loads - which is bad for both users and Google).

**Example using a more appropriate max-height**: `max-height: 100px` - you can see the slide down is now closer to the 1-second time you specified.

```css
.so-accordion-wrapper {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 820px;
}

.so-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.so-tab label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.so-tab input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.so-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

/* :checked */
.so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
    max-height: 100px;
}

/* Icon */
.so-tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #959595;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {

  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">INGREDIENTS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Yes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-2">PRECAUTION</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>No</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, it might not be a big deal as 0.35s is quite fast anyway, but this is a very important point to remember in general, as it can have a much larger affect in other situations.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, great read and understanding of why the action of the slider wasn't happening and also why the slider was at different speeds going up and down.

Thank you @FluffyKitten

Comment: @josh Glad it helps! I always try to offer an explanation so that users can learn from the answer as well as just fixing the problem :)  Fixing the problem now is ok, but if you (or other users) run into this problem again when it is more obvious, it can be very confusing if you don't understand why it seems to work in one place and not another!

Answer (score 1):

`Max-height` to `none` is the issue here, you should give a value in `pixels` and play with the `transition` seconds.

Nothing else should change.Check my solution.

```css
    .so-accordion-wrapper {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 820px;
}

.so-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.so-tab label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.so-tab input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.so-tab-content {
    max-height:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .75s;  //increase the seconds for more delay
}

/* :checked */
.so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
    max-height:100px;
}

/* Icon */
.so-tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #959595;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {

  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
    <div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
      <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">INGREDIENTS</label>
        <div class="so-tab-content">
          <p>Yes</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="so-tab">
        <input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> 
        <label for="so-tab-2">PRECAUTION</label>
        <div class="so-tab-content">
          <p>No</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This only works with a specific height, and based on the code provided the OP doesn't want this. Also,  `.so-tab input:checked` is not an error - that part of the code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, however css cannot create a transition from `max-height: 0` to `max-height: none`. when using a value using pixels you should be able to pull it off, see my fiddle here with a transition:

```css
.so-accordion-wrapper {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 820px;
}

.so-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.so-tab label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.so-tab input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.so-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

/* :checked */
.so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Icon */
.so-tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #959595;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {

  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">INGREDIENTS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Yes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-2">PRECAUTION</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>No</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nick, it is true the `max-height` is the main problem , but as I mentioned in my comment above - this still doesn't fix the strange behaviour of different speeds. It is more obvious if you change the .35s to 1s for example.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, can you explain it to me more. Not so technically gifted. I would like to learn the behaviour your talking about

Comment: @josh Firstly, the only change you need to get it to work is the `max-height: 1000px` - the rest of the code changes here are unnecessary. The problem I refer to is: if you change the max-height to e.g. 1000px, the slide down is very quick - if you change the transition duration to , e.g. `transition: max-height 1s;` you can see it more clearly - the div slides down quickly (but much more quickly than 1second), but it slides up correctly i.e. it takes 1 second.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Oh, yup, I see what you mean there. To be fair, I don't think my customers would notice this, the function works like 99% as I wanted. Don't think that diference in closing would be for me something to worry about

Comment: @josh It might not be important now, but but is something that might become an issue in future or in other circumstances. I've added an answer to explain this in more detail. Also, FYI you only need a single change to your codde to make it work - the other changes in the accepted answer are unnecessary. If you want to use them that's fine and totally your choice! But as you are just learning, its just so you know that you don't need them to get this to work (and some don't so anything anyway) so you can learn from the answers :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten, All good, I've read your answer and accepted it as the best solution without uneccessary extra changes. I also thought it was the best solution as it explained the reason for the error and the other error. Thank you!